# define steps of 250 to leftAxis using iOS-charts

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

I am trying to create a line chart using the [danielgindi/ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) library.
[image]

This works quite well so far. However, I cannot set the values on the left axis in 250 steps as desired.You can see my last attempt here:

```
ChartYAxis *leftAxis = self.lineChartView.leftAxis;
leftAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"ColorGraphSD"];
leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0;
leftAxis.axisMaximum = ceil(maxValue / 250.0) * 250;
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = YES;
leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.granularityEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.granularity = .1;
leftAxis.axisRange = 250;
leftAxis.labelCount = ceil(maxValue / 250.0);
```

Debugger tells me leftAxis.labelCount = 8; and leftAxis.axisMaximum = 2000;

All I want is a line at 250,500,750....

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **9** labels, not **8**, because you need to include the Zero label.

Also, setting `.granularity = 250.0;` will give you "steps" at 250 increments.

Example:

```
ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _chartView.leftAxis;
leftAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionOutsideChart;
leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0;
leftAxis.axisMaximum = 2000.0;

// use .granularity
leftAxis.granularity = 250.0;

// we need 9 labels to include the Zero label
leftAxis.labelCount = 9;
```

Output:

[image]